# Separated asset and ddp server for meteor mobile apps

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

Is there a way to separate asset and ddp servers for clients running meteor mobile apps (IOS/Android). For web apps it's simple just need to setup ROOT_URL for DDP service and deliver the content of the app from a different server.

In case of mobile app option --server is working for both parts at the same time. Mobile apps will be updating assets from the server as connecting to DDP server.

For purpose of caching and distribution content for a large scale application we need to have separate channels for assets and for ddp connections.

Comment: This should be possible with nginx in front of Meteor - you could proxy pass requests for assets to a different server (even a CDN) while leaving DDP requests unaffected.

Comment: This [article](http://joshowens.me/using-a-cdn-with-your-production-meteor-app/) on using Meteor with CloudFront might be useful